# Path `/boot/grub' is not readable by GRUB on boot. Installation is impossible. Aborting

Tags: linux, grub2, grub, btrfs, slackware

Whenever I try updating grub, I get this error:

```
# grub-install /dev/sda
Path `/boot/grub' is not readable by GRUB on boot. Installation is impossible. Aborting.
```

and

```
# grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg 
/usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for / (is /dev mounted?).
```

Also, I'm using the btrfs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This must be run first:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts 
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

Plus, if booted off a flash recovery drive,

```
chroot /mnt
```

([source](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/%60-boot-grub%27-is-not-readable-by-grub-on-boot-and-cannot-find-a-device-for-4175529366/page2.html#post5293488))